# How to set static IP address using connman for wifi network

Tags: linux, wifi, dhcp, static-ip-address, connman

I'm trying to set a static IP(manual, no dhcp) address for wifi network using connmanctl. I'm running angstrom linux.

I get the following:

connmanctl
connmanctl> config wifi_"HASH"_managed_psk --ipv4 manual 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1
Error wifi_"HASH"_managed_psk: Not supported

anyone has an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get a static IP address by manually creating a file named "settings" inside the directory:

```
  /var/lib/connman/wifi_<HASH>_managed_psk/
```

with the following content:

```
[wifi_<HASH>_managed_psk] 
Name=<SSID>                       ←Name of the network 
SSID=544f52414445585f4252         ←Name of the network in hexadecimal format    
Favorite=true
IPv4.method=manual                ←Method to be used (in this case manual IP)
IPv4.netmask_prefixlen=24
IPv4.local_address=192.168.0.133  ←Desired IP address
IPv4.gateway=192.168.0.1
Passphrase=<PASS>                 ←Wifi network password
AutoConnect=true
```

then activated and connected to the wifi

```
connmanctl enable wifi
connmanctl connect wifi_<HASH>_managed_psk
```

Comment: the answer can also be found here http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/wi-fi-(linux)#configuring-wi-fi-with-static-ip-address

Comment: for some reason, it's not taking the desired ip address. it's auto fetching some random ip . what might cause this ?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of editing settings under `/var/lib/connman/wifi_<HASH>_managed_psk/`, one should edit the config file **/var/lib/connman/*service-name*.config** instead.

e.g.

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/connman$ sudo cat wifi.config
[service_home]
Type = wifi
Name = yyyyyyyyy
Security = wpa
Passphrase = xxxxxxxxxx
IPv4=192.168.1.4/255.255.255.0/192.168.1.254
IPv6=off
Nameservers=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

For details, refer to the man page [connman-service.config](https://www.mankier.com/5/connman-service.config)

Comment: you got a dead link there

Comment: Because the link in the answer is broken: https://github.com/aldebaran/connman/blob/master/doc/config-format.txt and https://man.archlinux.org/man/connman-service.config.5

Answer (score -1):

Try `connmanctl enable wifi` then you should be able to configure it

Answer (score -1):

once you install `connman` then it create configuration directory in  `/var/lib/connman` where devices like wifi ,Ethernet etc. configuration file is created. in those file there is entry like :

```
[service_wifi_<HASH>_managed_psk]
Type = wifi
Name = <SSID>
Passphrase = <PASSPHRASE>   
IPv4.method=dhcp
```

open that file and see given name is correct that you are using in command

```
connmanctl config wifi_"HASH"_managed_psk --ipv4 manual 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1
```

if other than `wifi_"HASH"_managed_psk` then use that . or you can see by using command `connmanctl services`